# Ubuntu 16.04 booting very slow

Tags: 16.04, boot, uefi

I fresh installed Ubuntu 16.04 along with Windows 10 in UEFI mode. Booting time was normal when I installed it. After I did **apt upgrade**, booting time has increased.

Output of **systemd-analyze blame**:

```
     24.771s dev-sda6.device
     12.795s systemd-udevd.service
      7.089s gpu-manager.service
      7.023s NetworkManager-wait-online.service
      6.925s systemd-tmpfiles-setup-dev.service
      4.919s systemd-sysctl.service
      3.829s snapd.service
      3.216s NetworkManager.service
      3.065s accounts-daemon.service
      2.955s ModemManager.service
      2.498s thermald.service
      2.008s udisks2.service
      1.954s systemd-modules-load.service
      1.863s keyboard-setup.service
      1.512s tlp.service
      1.325s grub-common.service
      1.030s systemd-journald.service
       909ms dev-hugepages.mount
       907ms dev-mqueue.mount
       906ms sys-kernel-debug.mount
       716ms systemd-fsck@dev-disk-by\x2duuid-445B\x2d8843.service
       700ms apparmor.service
       657ms ufw.service
       600ms console-setup.service
       570ms upower.service
       546ms systemd-tmpfiles-setup.service
       461ms rsyslog.service
       439ms kmod-static-nodes.service
       415ms irqbalance.service
       414ms wpa_supplicant.service
       349ms bluetooth.service
       316ms polkitd.service
       278ms colord.service
       215ms avahi-daemon.service
       201ms apport.service
       166ms snapd.socket
       159ms lightdm.service
       141ms plymouth-read-write.service
       135ms systemd-update-utmp.service
       132ms systemd-remount-fs.service
       111ms user@1000.service
        91ms setvtrgb.service
        80ms boot-efi.mount
        80ms systemd-hostnamed.service
        78ms systemd-udev-trigger.service
        63ms networking.service
        62ms systemd-timesyncd.service
        47ms systemd-journal-flush.service
        36ms systemd-logind.service
        33ms ondemand.service
        28ms systemd-random-seed.service
        27ms speech-dispatcher.service
        15ms systemd-user-sessions.service
        14ms plymouth-start.service
        11ms alsa-restore.service
        10ms snapd.autoimport.service
        10ms pppd-dns.service
         6ms dns-clean.service
         4ms rtkit-daemon.service
         4ms ureadahead-stop.service
         4ms systemd-update-utmp-runlevel.service
         4ms resolvconf.service
         3ms sys-fs-fuse-connections.mount
         2ms rc-local.service
         1ms systemd-backlight@backlight:intel_backlight.service
         1ms plymouth-quit-wait.service
         1ms nvidia-persistenced.service
```

Output of systemd-analyze time:

```
Startup finished in 3.498s (firmware) + 3.332s (loader) + 6.081s (kernel) 
+ 3min 3.648s (userspace) = 3min 16.561s
```

System info:

```
Laptop
Memory: 8 GB
Processor: Intel® Core™ i5-8250U CPU @ 1.60GHz × 8
Graphic: Intel® Kabylake GT1.5 and NVIDIA MX150(disabled)
```

Content of /etc/fstab

```
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5). 
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda6 during installation
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=445B-8843  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# swap was on /dev/sda7 during installation
# UUID=96ded05b-556c-4459-9bcc-184ac5c21c2f none            swap    sw                  0       0
/dev/mapper/cryptswap1 none swap sw 0 0
UUID=8534b107-3576-4f00-9150-2081f1e2f430 / ext4 rw,relatime,data=ordered 0 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Huh, super weird.

> Startup finished in 3.498s (firmware) + 3.332s (loader) + 6.081s (kernel) 
>   + 3min 3.648s (userspace) = 3min 16.561s

What's taking 3 mins in userspace?

Also, these two:

```
 24.771s dev-sda6.device
 12.795s systemd-udevd.service
```

Make me thing there's a problem with starting up the disk drive.  Is the disk going bad?  Are you doing anything out of the ordinary in `etc/fstab`?  Disk encryption?

I'd start by looking into how your drives are being mounted.

Also, Microsoft takes extra special time and attention to mess up multi-OS installs.  I use Linux exclusively on my laptop for that reason - I have a cheap desktop with Windows for compatibility testing.

UEFI is pretty much {insert rant}.  Microsoft likes this because it has plenty of payola.  Turning off UEFI in the BIOS may help (but Windows may complain).

Comment: This is a new laptop. I bought it 2 weeks ago. Check the content of  /etc/fstab in the question I edited.

Comment: What are these two **24.771s dev-sda6.device
 12.795s systemd-udevd.service**? Will disabling them have any effect on system?

Comment: "Turning off UEFI in the BIOS" is impossible. Modern computers are all UEFI-based (or EFI-based, for Macs), not BIOS-based, despite the fact that most people, and even manufacturers, continue to use the inaccurate term "BIOS." Furthermore, computers boot in either BIOS/CSM/legacy mode (using a BIOS emulator) or in native EFI/UEFI mode, and the boot mode is determined largely by the boot loader. Thus, even if you activate the CSM, it will probably not change the boot mode; it will just make BIOS-mode booting possible, which will actually complicate the boot path, making new problems likely.

Comment: @BatMan Hmmm...  I don't see anything strange in the fstab.  Have you checked the system logs for errors on those services?  https://www.howtogeek.com/117878/how-to-view-write-to-system-log-files-on-ubuntu/